# Sorting the admin columns by a custom field is not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I have added two custom fields to the columns of my admin area and made them sortable. One includes a invoice number, one includes the price for the invoice. Sorting the posts by the price works fine. Unfortunately sorting the posts by the invoice number is not working at all.

This is how I included the new columns:

```
/**
 * Add custom columns for Projects
 */
add_filter("manage_project_posts_columns", "project_custom_columns");
function project_custom_columns($columns){
  $new = array();
  foreach($columns as $key => $title) {
    if ($key=='date') {
      $new["invoice_id"] = "Invoice Number";
      $new["price"] = "Price";
    }
    $new[$key] = $title;
  }
  return $new;
}


/**
 * Make project list sortable for invoice id and price
 */
add_filter( 'manage_edit-project_sortable_columns', 'project_custom_sort' );
function project_custom_sort( $columns ) {
    $columns['invoice_id'] = 'Invoice Number';
    $columns['price'] = 'Price';

    return $columns;
}


/**
 * Manage project list sorting for invoice id and price
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_orderby' );
function custom_orderby( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

    if( 'Invoice Number' == $orderby ) {
      $query->set('meta_key','billed_invoice_number');
      $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
    } else if( 'Price' == $orderby ) {
      $query->set('meta_key','project_price');
      $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
      $query->set( 'meta_type', 'numeric' );
    }
}
```

I wonder if it has something to do with the values of `billed_invoice_number`, e.g. '2018-D22-008', '2018-D28-001', '2018-D47-001', '2018-D22-005'.

Do you have any idea why the sorting might not be working with these values?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to remove the `$query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');` for the `billed_invoice_number` meta.

Comment: Oh god, I am such a fool, thanks for the hint: I replaced `$query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');`with `$query->set('orderby','meta_value');`and everything work fine now. Can you put this in a real answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: I've put a "real" answer, and hopefully it's not "overly-answered" and that it will also help others. =)

Comment: There is no "overly-answered" ;) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if it has something to do with the values of
>   `billed_invoice_number`, e.g. '2018-D22-008', '2018-D28-001',
>   '2018-D47-001', '2018-D22-005'

Yes, it has. =)

So a simple fix, is to change the `orderby` value for the `billed_invoice_number` from `meta_value_num` to `meta_value` as in:

```
if( 'Invoice Number' == $orderby ) {
  $query->set('meta_key','billed_invoice_number');
  $query->set('orderby','meta_value'); // <- this
} else if( 'Price' == $orderby ) {
  ...
}
```

> Do you have any idea why the sorting might not be working with these
>   values?

Because we use `meta_value_num` only for meta (or custom field) where the value is a ***numeric* value** like `1`, `1.00`, `0.1`, `-1`, `-1.23`, etc.

So for example the `2018-D22-008`, *why it doesn't work*?

- Short answer: Because it is *not* a numeric value.
- Longer answer: When the `orderby` is set to `meta_value_num`, the `WP_Query` class will instruct MySQL to convert the meta value to a numeric value in this way: `{meta value} + 0`, which is equivalent to PHP's `intval( {meta value} )` or `(int) {meta value}`. So `'201822008' + 0` works, but not `'2018-D22-008' + 0` which results in `2018`.

Therefore, with the example `billed_invoice_number` values you provided, they were converted to `2018` (i.e. the numbers before the first `-`), which in turn failed to be *sorted as expected*. :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Actually I was looking for your "long answer" yesterday as well, when I wanted to understand how Wordpress is handling the orderby at all. Great, thanks!